# When user click on alert button open mobile browser and display URL on android apps

Tags: java, android

When user click on alert massage know more button open mobile browser and display URL of my website on android apps what I have made.I need the code. I have tried many code like web view and others, but not working. Please help me!

Below Code not working.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_about:


            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NoteEdit.this);
            dialog.setTitle("About");
            dialog.setMessage("Hello!);
            dialog.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }});
            dialog.setPositiveButton("KNOW MORE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String url = "http://www.google.com";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                 }
                });
```

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means.

Comment: You need to call `create()` and `show()` for the created dialog at the end of code.

Answer (score 3):

Below code perfect working in my case:
Create 
Define private static final int DIALOG_EXIT = 1;
now create

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_EXIT:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("About")
                .setMessage("Hello")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Know More",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                /*Uri uri = Uri
                                        .parse("http://www.google.com");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                startActivity(intent);*/
                                 String url = "http://www.google.com";
                                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                    startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
    dialog = builder.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

and you just called this from your menu item selected function;

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.setting:
        showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

try this this may help you.

Comment: showDialog() is deprecated since API 13. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog(int, android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 1):

this code works for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to show your dialog. At the end, dd the line

```
dialog.show()
```

Also, in the line

```
dialog.setMessage("Hello!);
```

you are missing an ending quote.